# Background Task in ASP.NET Core 1.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I have some tasks that require a lot of time to be executed and that I would like to run in background, so that the server can send the response to the client before the task is completed.

One working solution is the following:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> MyAction(){
    var result = await SimpleOperation();
    Task.Run(() => BackgroundOperation()); //i.e. send email
    return View(result);
}
```

As you know, Task.Run enqueues the task in the thread pool and it will be run as soon as possible.

However Sonar Lint does not like it because Task.Run returns a Task and it is not awaited.

From .NET Core 2.1 it is possible to use BackgroundServices and shared queues to handle the execution of background Tasks:

```
public interface IBackgroundTaskQueue {
    void Enqueue(Func<Task> taskFactory);
    Task Dequeue();
    bool HasItems();
}

public class MyBackgroundService : BackgroundService {
    private readonly IBackgroundTaskQueue _queue;
    public MyBackgroundService (IBackgroundTaskQueue queue) {
        queue = _queue
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while(true)
        {
           if (queue.HasItems())
           {
               await queue.Dequeue(); //this call awaits the task to end
           }
           else
           {
               await Task.Delay(1000);
           }
        }    
    }
}

public class MyController {
    private readonly IBackgroundTaskQueue _queue;
    public MyController (IBackgroundTaskQueue queue) {
        queue = _queue
    }
    public async Task<ActionResult> MyAction(){
        var result = await SimpleOperation();
        _queue.Enqueue(() => BackgroundOperation()); //i.e. send email
        return View(result);
    }
}
```

But this is not supported in .NET Core 1.0

What is the best solution for .NET Core 1.0? Should I use Task.Run and ignore Sonar Lint error?

Comment: .NET Core 1.0 isn's supported. It went out of support years ago. Just don't use it. No, you can't use `Task.Run` in any web application, whether it's .NET Framework or .NET Core. Your job may not run at all, or get disposed as soon as the request ends

Comment: The long-term-support versions are .NET Core 2.1 and 3.1.

Comment: For sending email I would probably go for a statefull queue and than just a thread that reads it and sends the mail. (Or separate service)

Comment: @Magnus that's what the [queued BackgroundService example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#queued-background-tasks) shows in the docs. There's no need for a separate service only for that. It's a good choice if multiple apps or servers need to run scheduled jobs though

Comment: A *very* good solution is to use a package like [HangFire](https://www.hangfire.io) to schedule *and* monitor background jobs.

Comment: Is that a statefull queue in that example?

Comment: Hi @Magnus, do you mean to enqueue the tasks in a DB or something like this? I would use this solution as a last hope.

Comment: No, if you host in Azure for example you could use something like the Service bus.
And you want state because if the app crashes or server needs restart you don't want to lose your queued items.

Comment: @Magnus The app is hosted on premise